# How to split row value according to specific column?

Tags: sql-server, split, sql-update, row, multiple-columns

I have Table A and Table B and I'm having trouble getting the fulfilled qty in Table B where sum up of Fulfilled qty is equal to Available field in Table A.

For Item ID 1, the available qty is 99 in Table A and in Table B this Item ID 1 have different rack, with 99 qty, it only able to fulfill 60 qty for Rack A and remaining 39 qty for Rack B.

Table A

```
ID   Available
1    99
2    5
```

Table B

```
ID  Rack  Required 
1    A    60    
1    B    102    
1    C    8    
2    A    10
```

Desired Results

```
ID   Rack Required    Fulfilled 
1    A    60          60    
1    B    102         39    
1    C    8           0    
2    A    4           4
2    B    2           1
```

I have tried using query below but seems not able to get the expected results

```sql
SELECT ID,
       RACK,
       REQUIREDQTY,
       SUM(FULFILLEDQTY) OVER (ORDER BY ID,
                                        RACK,
                                        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) AS FULFILLEDQTY
FROM TABLEB
     LEFT JOIN TABLEA ON TABLEB.ID = TABLEA.ID;
```

Comment: In your query you reference the column `FULFILLEDQTY` in your windowed `SUM`, where is that coming from? It's not in your data.

Comment: sorry my bad, should be query below :- SELECT        ID, RACK,  REQUIRED, sum(AVAILABLE) over(order by ID, RACK, rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) FULFILLEDQTY
                          FROM   TABLEB
        left join TABLEA
        on TABLEB.ID = TABLEA.ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sum(Required) over (...)` and check against `Available`

```
select A.ID, B.Rack, B.Required,
       Fulfilled = case when sum(B.Required) over (partition by A.ID order by B.Rack) 
                        <=   A.Available
                        then B.Required
                        when sum(B.Required) over (partition by A.ID order by B.Rack) 
                        -    B.Required <= A.Available
                        then A.Available 
                        -    sum(B.Required) over (partition by A.ID order by B.Rack) 
                        +    B.Required
                        else 0
                        end
from   A
       inner join B on A.ID = B.ID
order by A.ID, B.Rack
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3514c6231f974bcb9b34d260e9a86987)

---

EDIT : due to change of structure (additional column `rack`)

```
select A.ID, A.rack, B.bin, B.Required,
       Fulfilled = case when sum(B.Required) over (partition by A.ID, A.rack 
                                                       order by B.bin) 
                        <=   A.Available
                        then B.Required
                        when sum(B.Required) over (partition by A.ID, A.rack 
                                                       order by B.bin) 
                        -    B.Required 
                        <=   A.Available
                        then A.Available 
                        -    sum(B.Required) over (partition by A.ID, A.rack
                                                       order by B.bin) 
                        +    B.Required
                        else 0
                        end
from   A
       inner join B on A.ID = B.ID and A.rack = B.rack
order by A.ID, A.rack,  B.bin
```

Comment: Thanks Squirrel for the info, I have tried out the query and when apply to another table where structure is a bit different, the results is not as expected. You may refer to the fiddle link  : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=18397eb1cd8bfe6420cf3225f33e35bf

Comment: 2 issues noted. Since `Rack` is now part of foreign key to table `A`, you should also include that in the `partition by` . It should be `sum(B.Required) over (partition by B.ID, B.Rack order by B.bin)`. Another issue is your `BIN` is not unique. You have multiple bin `E` for Rack `130`

Comment: The `multiple bin` is it a mistake or genuine case ?

Comment: Ok noted, thanks alot. Appreciate it.

Comment: The multiple bin is a mistake. Sorry my bad

Comment: Please accept the answer if this answer your question